# Issue in using coalesce and None within update query postgres

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I am updating postgres table from python using psycopg2 like below

Table: tab1

```
+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|Id                |name               |state              |added_time         |
+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|123               |test1              |True               |2022-04-29 09:08:46|
+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Schema:

```
Id: Int8
Name: text
state: boolean
added_time: timestamp
```

Query I am creating to update data is as below,

```
sql=UPDATE tab1 as org SET "name"=coalesce(new."name", org."name"),"state"=coalesce(new."state", org."state"),"added_time"=coalesce(new."added_time", org."added_time") 
                                    FROM (VALUES %s) as new ("name", "state", "added_time") WHERE (new."Id"=org."Id")
```

and finally running query with values as,

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(db_connection)
cur = conn.cursor()    
psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cur, sql, val) 

val = [123, "test", None, None]
```

I am getting exception as `psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch: COALESCE types text and boolean cannot be matched`

for state column and same is occurring for added_time when values are None. I am using coalesce to avoid updating null values if non null value is already present.
I have tried using nullif but it didn't work and also tried printing mogrified query to see what actual values are passed,

```
UPDATE tab1 as org SET "name"=coalesce(new."name", org."name"),"state"=coalesce(new."state", org."state"),"added_time"=coalesce(new."added_time", org."added_time")  \n                                FROM (VALUES ARRAY[123,"test",NULL,NULL]) as new ("Id","name","state","added_time") WHERE (new."Id"=org."Id")
```

Can anyone help here?

Comment: What happens if you make `val` a list with a single tuple, e.g. `val = [(123, "test", None, None)]` ?

Comment: Same error occurs @MikeOrganek

Comment: There are some issues with the code you are showing. For example, you are using `val` before defining it, and `val` seems to have too many elements. It should be possible to produce a minimal reproducible example for this, perhaps assuming an existing database but creating a temporary table to play with and stripping away unnecessary columns.